# Firebase and login, not a single tutorial is up to date not even on Google.. What is the correct way to do it?

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I am following this line by line 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

But the second I add

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
```

Open File

Or if I add the code:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

I get this error

ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.
Open File

How can I make a simple login and registration with firebase? I can't even find one single tutorial on google or Youtube.

Comment: Please try this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7XCRoZDqm6k&t=66s). It will help you to understand of setup of  firebase

Answer (score 0):

open your **build.gradle** file in app folder of your application, and add the following first line in build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```